# Multiprocessing Manager's shared memory on Spark Streaming raising authentication issues?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, spark-streaming

I am trying to share data across a spark streaming process and a http webservice using python's multiprocessing library.

A simple case of this is trying to share a counter (eg. multiprocessing.Value)

If I try a simply spark streaming job listening to kafka:

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient

from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Manager, current_process



def ss_kafka_counter(zkQuorum, topic, timeinterval, send_msg_func):

    sc = SparkContext(appName="KafkaCounter")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, timeinterval)

    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    interval_counts = (lines.map(lambda line: (line, 1))
                            .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b))

    # interval_counts.pprint()
    interval_counts.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(send_msg_func))

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

def create_send_http_func(mp_counter):

    def mp_poplate_storage(iters):
        for item, count in iters:
            mp_counter.value += count

    return mp_poplate_storage

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        brokers, topic, timeinterval = sys.argv[1:]
        timeinterval = int(timeinterval)

        mg = Manager()
        mp_counter = mg.Value('i', 0)

        send_http_func = create_send_http_func(mp_counter)
        count_kafka_service = Process(target=ss_kafka_counter,
                                      args=(brokers, topic, timeinterval,
                                            send_http_func))
        count_kafka_service.start()
        count_kafka_service.join()

    else:
        exit(-1)
```

This causes some issues

```
    5/08/03 13:27:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 88, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 156, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 405, in loads
    return cPickle.loads(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 878, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 733, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 782, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 175, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 427, in answer_challenge
    raise AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected')
AuthenticationError: (AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected',), <function RebuildProxy at 0x113bf7f50>, (<class 'multiprocessing.managers.ValueProxy'>, Token(typeid='Value', address='/var/folders/27/3dv1vhwx3lg6qj7c60xzft9m8wdqc7/T/pymp-DOuoZY/listener-58AwcR', id='112c35110'), 'pickle', {}))

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/03 13:27:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 88, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 156, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/Users/kelvin/Git/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 405, in loads
    return cPickle.loads(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 878, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 733, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 782, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 175, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 427, in answer_challenge
    raise AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected')
AuthenticationError: (AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected',), <function RebuildProxy at 0x113bd41b8>, (<class 'multiprocessing.managers.ValueProxy'>, Token(typeid='Value', address='/var/folders/27/3dv1vhwx3lg6qj7c60xzft9m8wdqc7/T/pymp-DOuoZY/listener-58AwcR', id='112c35110'), 'pickle', {}))

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The reason why I bother to put try and manage the processes is because I was try to create a RESTful http service that could be used to query for the the data (thus avoiding writing to disk/some database)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was stupid of me. The answer has to do with the fact that the shared value is only shared with the driver spark process. The error occured because the shared variable isn't shared with the other worker processes, and I am trying to access the shared value on those worker processes. The way to accomplish what I was trying to do is to use accumulators and then write the value of the accumulators to the shared variable in the driver process.